# How to derive this second derivative using the quotient rule?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If a given first derivative is: $\ {dy \over dx} = {-48x \over (x^2+12)^2} $

What are the steps using the quotient rule to derive the second derivative: $\ {d^2y \over dx^2} = {-144(4-x^2) \over (x^2+12)^3} $

My Steps:

\begin{align*}
{d^2y \over dx^2}
&= {-48(x^2 +12)^2 - 2(x^2+12)(2x)(-48x)\over (x^2+12)^4} \\
&=-48{(x^2 +12)^2 - 4x^2(x^2+12)\over (x^2+12)^4} \\
&= -48{(x^2 +12)( - 4x^2 +(x^2+12))\over (x^2+12)^4} \\
&=  -48{(x^2 +12)( - 4x^2)\over (x^2+12)^3} \\
&= {???}
\end{align*}

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Writing down the steps now. Will edit in a moment.

Comment: ^that's the spirit! (+1)

Comment: Edited to show where I am getting lost at.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 do you think you could help me identify my mistake from the edit that shows my steps?

Comment: Your last step is wrong. Pay attention to where the parentheses are and such.

Comment: Just saw this. Are you still stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can factor out the constant term to make life easier (and just multiply by that $-48$ at the end of our calculation) as:

$$-48 \dfrac{x}{(x^2+12)^2}$$

This makes it easier to use the quotient and chain rule (I will assume you know these).

The derivative of $\ {dy \over dx} = {-48x \over (x^2+12)^2} $, using the quotient and chain rule is:

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = -48 \dfrac{(1)(x^2+12)^2 - 2(x^2+12)(2x)x}{(x^2+12)^4} = -48 \dfrac{(x^2+12) - 2(2x)x}{(x^2+12)^3} = \dfrac{-144(4-x^2)}{(x^2+12)^3}$

Comment: I am getting up to the second portion of your solution. Where does the -144 come from?

Comment: You are also using another rule, by factoring out the $-48$. Any chance you'd care to show where each rule comes into play? Obviously everyone who *already knows* how to do this calculation will have no trouble following along, but the OP seems lost.

Comment: Factor an $(x^2+12)^1$ from the numerator and cancel it with the denominator. Clear?

Comment: @user40650: Are you following this and got it?

Comment: Edited the post to show where I am getting before I get confused. How would I get from my last step to the solution?

Comment: Your problem is the $-48x$ term, that should be multiplied, not subtracted. For the second equality just do the factor of $(x^2+12)$ from the numerator and cancel with denominator. Got it?

Comment: Nice work +1 And you've been busy!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you know what the quotient rule is - which you can derive from the product rule say by taking the derivative of $g(x)/f(x)$.

Then, simplify. Looking at the product rule, expect to have to cancel a factor of $x^2+12$ from the top and bottom.

Comment: Re: the now-deleted answer to this question. I agree that we should not spoon-feed answer. However, "should" represents a pedagogical philosophy that is far from universal.

Answer (score -1):

Recall the Quotient Rule:

$$(\frac{f}{g})' = \frac{f'\cdot g - g' \cdot f}{g^2}$$

So you have the first derivative, $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{-48x}{(x^2+12)^2}$. Just apply the quotient rule:

Let $f(x) = -48x$. So $f'(x) = -48$.
Let $g(x) = (x^2 + 12)^2$. So, by the chain rule, $g'(x) = 2(x^2 + 12) \cdot 2x = 4x(x^2+12)$.

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{(-48 \cdot (x^2+12)^2) - (4x(x^2+12) \cdot -48x)}{((x^2+12)^2)^2}$$
Notice that both elements of the numerator contain $-48$. We can factor that out.
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{-48 \cdot ((x^2+12) - (4x^2(x^2+12)))}{(x^2+12)^4}$$
We also can factor out the $(x^2+12)^2$ term:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{-48 \cdot (x^2+12) \cdot ((x^2+12) - 4x^2)}{(x^2+12)^4}$$
And now we can cancel:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{-48 \cdot (12 - 3x^2)}{(x^2+12)^3}$$
Observe that we can factor the numerator some more:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{-48 \cdot 3 \cdot (4 - x^2)}{(x^2+12)^3}$$
And there we are:
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{-144 \cdot (4 - x^2)}{(x^2+12)^3}$$

Comment: Your denominator is funky funky.

Comment: My impression is this kind of question should be answered with hints - not a direct answer.

Comment: @dfeuer embarrassing mistake; fixed.

Comment: @levitopher Possibly, but I try not to read too much into the question asked by the person. Above all, I try to provide an informative and clear answer.