# Where am I going wrong on this second derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If a given first derivative is: $\ {dy \over dx} = {-48x \over (x^2+12)^2} $

What are the steps using the quotient rule to derive the second derivative: $\ {d^2y \over dx^2} = {-144(4-x^2) \over (x^2+12)^3} $

My Steps:

$$ {{d^2y \over dx^2} = {-48(x^2 +12)^2 - 2(x^2+12)(2x)(-48x)\over (x^2+12)^4} =-48{(x^2 +12)^2 - 4x^2(x^2+12)\over (x^2+12)^4} = -48{(x^2 +12)( - 4x^2 +(x^2+12))\over (x^2+12)^4} =  -48{(x^2 +12)( - 4x^2)\over (x^2+12)^3} = ???}
 $$

Once I get to this point I am unsure how to derive the second derivative shown.

Comment: You made an error in your last step: somehow addition became multiplication, in the numerator.

Comment: You asked this question a little while earlier. I've provided a very thorough answer as of a few minutes ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/541708/98587

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'=-\frac{48x}{(x^2+12)^2}\Rightarrow y''=\left(-\frac{48x}{(x^2+12)^2}\right)'=-48\left(\frac{x}{(x^2+12)^2}\right)'$$$$=-48\frac{x'\cdot(x^2+12)^2-x((x^2+12)^2)'}{(x^2+12)^4)}=-48\frac{(x^2+12)^2-4x^2(x^2+12)}{(x^2+12)^4}$$
$$=-48\frac{(x^2+12)(x^2+12-4x^2)}{(x^2+12)^4}=-48\frac{12-3x^2}{(x^2+12)^3}=-48\cdot 3\frac{4-x^2}{(x^2+12)^3}=-144\frac{4-x^2}{(x^2+12)^3}$$

Answer (score 2):

You made a small mistake on the last step: $-4 x^2 + (x^2 + 12) \not= -4 x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You've got your error as indicated in the comments, but I suggest you to consider the fraction as below:

$$y'=(-48x)(x^{12}+2)^{\color{red}{-2}}$$ So you have touse just this rule that $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$ and $(u^n)'=nu^{n-1}\times u'$.